# Can multiple threads acquire lock on the same object?

Tags: multithreading

I am taking a course on concurrency. The text says that multi-threading allows high throughput as it takes advantage of the multiples cores of the cpu.

I have a question about locking in the context of multiple cores. If we have multiple threads and they are running in different cpu cores, why can't two threads acquire the same lock? How does os protect against such scenarios?

Comment: Well, that is arch dependent, and the method used on Itanium Windows XP, could potentially be different from Arm on an iPhone, or amd x86-64 in linux... generally there is some sort of guarantee in some low level instruction that allows you to structure a guaranteed execution order and therefore and orderly locking behavior across multiple cores/threads/sockets...

Comment: Re, "why can't two threads acquire the same lock?" Are you asking how locks work? or are you really asking _why?_. The reason why is because that's the whole point of locks. It's to prevent two or more threads from using the same shared data at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Locking and locks are for synchronization to prevent data corruption when multiple threads want to write to the same memory.

Generally you run multiple threads and use locking only in critical situations.
If two or more threads want to write into the same place at the same time then the multi core calculation is limited. Of course you can use no locking in this situation but results can be unpredictable at that moment.

For example to write multi-threaded calculation of matrix multiplication you make a thread for every row of the resulting matrix. There is no locking needed because every thread writes to different place and this scenario can fully benefit from multiple processors.

If you want to permit more than one shared access to a resource then you can use Semaphore (in java).

Answer (score 0):

> If we have multiple threads and they are running in different cpu cores, why can't two threads acquire the same lock?

The purpose of mutex/lock is to implement [*mutual exclusion*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion) - only one thread can lock a mutex at a time. Or, in other words, many threads cannot lock the same mutex at the same time, by definition. This mechanism is needed to allow multiple threads to store into or read from a shared non-atomic resource without [data race](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Data_race) conditions.

> How does os protect against such scenarios?

OS support is needed to prevent the threads from busy-waiting when locking a mutex that is already locked by another thread. Linux implementations of mutex (and semaphore) use [`futex`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/futex.2.html) to put the waiting threads to sleep and wake them up when the mutex is released.

[Here is a longer explanation from Linus Torvalds of how mutex is implemented.](https://www.realworldtech.com/forum/?threadid=189711&curpostid=189755)